# "Uncaught Error: You need to call Parse.initialize before using Parse" in a Svelte app

Tags: svelte, parse-server, back4app

That same error appeared for many developers before, but none of them used Svelte, problem is I have it already initialized in main.js

```js
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';
const appID=import.meta.env['APP_ID'];
const PARSE_HOST_URL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
const jsKey = import.meta.env['JS_ID'];
Parse.initialize(appID, jsKey);
Parse.serverURL = PARSE_HOST_URL;
```

When I got that error I tried pasting this code again inside the component that should read the data but there was no difference. I also tried pasting the code from back4app documentation (where the DB is hosted).

```html
<script context="module">
import Parse from 'parse/dist/parse.min.js';
export const Members = async function () {
    // Reading parse objects is done by using Parse.Query
    const parseQuery = new Parse.Query('members');
    try {
        let memberList = await parseQuery.find();
        return memberList;
    } catch (error) {
        alert('Error! '+error.message);
    };
};
</script>
```

the env file is located in the main root directory, did I put it in the wrong location or am I missing something?

Update: this is the previous version of the app written in vanilla js

```
Parse.initialize([app_key], [js_key]);
Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com/";
const membersDiv=document.querySelector('.memberlist');
const namesList=document.querySelector('.names');
let members = Parse.Object.extend("members");
let query = new Parse.Query(members).limit(1000);
query.find().then(function(results) {
results.forEach(function(member) {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
    let namesList = document.createElement('li');
    namesList.classList.add('member');
    namesList.innerHTML = ` <p class="name">${member.get('name')}</p><p class="memberid">${member.get('memberid')}</p><p><a href="tel:${member.get('phone')}">${member.get('phone')}</a></p>`;
    if (member.get('phone')===undefined){
      namesList.innerHTML = ` <p class="name">${member.get('name')}</p><p class="memberid">${member.get('memberid')}</p><p>${member.get('phone')}</p>`;
    }
    if (typeof member.get('phone')!="undefined"&& member.get('phone').substring(0,1)!='0'){
      namesList.innerHTML = ` <p class="name">${member.get('name')}</p><p class="memberid">${member.get('memberid')}</p><p><a href="tel:${'0'+member.get('phone')}">${'0'+member.get('phone')}</a></p>`;
    }
    membersDiv.appendChild(namesList);
    // create 5 checkboxes for each member
    let checkboxes = document.createElement('div');
    checkboxes.classList.add('checkboxes');
    namesList.appendChild(checkboxes);
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.classList.add('w'+parseInt(i+1));
        checkboxes.appendChild(checkbox);
        if (member.get('w'+parseInt(i+1)) == true) {
            // check the first checkbox
            checkboxes.children[i].checked = true;
        }
        // when a checkbox is checked, update the member object
        checkboxes.children[i].onclick = function() {
            member.set('w'+parseInt(i+1), this.checked);
            member.save();
            if (member.save()){
              console.log(members.name)
            } else{
              console.log('error')
            }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It's the order that you call `Parse.intialzie` and other API like `Parse.Query`. The code you post bears no obvious mistake. How do you use the `Members` function? It's the missing key info to your pb.

Comment: Also, how does this unnamed svelte component connect with `main.js` file? Do you import it or what? Show that part too.

Comment: @hackape I use import for everything, above is all of the component's code, do I need to import main.js or do I have to do something more?

Comment: Need to see more code about usage of the `Members` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of Back4app support team:
The latest version (3.5.0) of Parse SDK seems to have some bugs (already fixed, but not released yet). Change it to : "parse": "3.4.4"

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't use Parse reference after that initialized Parse reference.

You should try over the Parse variable you initialized where you got the error.

Comment: the variable is what's causing the problem, I called this variable twice, in the component and main js file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

Paste this in each component you want to use, just before the 'return' with your own app id and js key and it should work fine:

```
const PARSE_APPLICATION_ID = 'YOUR_APPLICATION_ID_HERE';
const PARSE_HOST_URL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
const PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY = 'YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY_HERE';
Parse.initialize(PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, PARSE_JAVASCRIPT_KEY);
Parse.serverURL = PARSE_HOST_URL;
```